# is there away to check if a Google account is part of specific community in Google+

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus

i'm building an app for a Google plus community, an app can be only opened by the community members only.
is there away i can check if the user is part of this community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=523).